# How to say "come and vote" in Russian?

Tags: лексикон

I have two ways to say it:

```
Дай свой  голос!
Проголосуйте!
```

The context is that there is a big voting going on and I want to invite Russian speaking people to come and vote also for the greater good.

Which way is the correct way to invite people to vote and why?

Comment: Tell them you want 100% participation, not 146%.

Comment: @KCd Which one means that I want 146% ? :D

Comment: @Jaanus It was a reference to one of the early TV reports on the last Presidental Election, now widely recognized in Russia as a meme. Perhaps a screenshot from Russia24 TV channel live broadcast would speak for itself better: http://is.gd/ccGXKb

Comment: corruption much?

Comment: Most certainly, sir.

Comment: what about ukraine?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but up until the end of 2013 my Ukrainian peers hated the establishment and didn't believe election results a jot because "everything's sold and bought".

Comment: "голосни!" :-DDDDDDD (joking)

Answer (score 6):

The most frequently used phrases are:

> Голосуй!
>   Отдай свой голос!

Both are correct.
The plural form is also usable:

> Голосуйте!
>   Отдайте свой голос!

In my humble opinion, first phrase is the most informal, whenever the last one - is the most formal.

Answer (score 3):

Don't say "Дай свой голос" - it is incorrect.
literal translation of "come and vote" would be:
"Приди и проголосуй!" 
or
"Приходите и голосуйте!"

I don't think we can say "Отдай свой голос!".
Seems incorrect to me.
But we can say "Отдай свой голос **за** something"

For example 
"Отдай свой голос **за** партию Чебурашки !" 
(Vote for Cheburashka's political party)

Answer (score 3):

"Дай свой голос" - is not correct, because "дай" means something we can really, physically give. We can say "Проголосуй" (прогосуйте) or "Отдай свой голос" (отдай свой голос за нового кандидата)